# Calendar Extender and iPad

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ipad, ajaxcontroltoolkit, z-index

I have a dynamically added calendar extender from the Ajax Control Toolkit that I'm adding to my page.  Additionally, I'm wrapping the entire page in a new div through javascript.  After adding this div, the calendar extender doesn't allow you to select a new date on the iPad.  In browsers, (safari, IE, firefox), the functionality works fine.  I'm not sure if this is some sort of z-index problem on the iPad or if there's something else going on here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**EDIT**

Upon further inspection, removing the overflow property from the surrounding div makes the calendar extender work.  However, I need to have the scrollability provided by overflow:auto.  Ideas?